# Angular2 application is not working after importing flexLayout

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create form using flexLayout in angular2 material. It gives syntaxError.

SyntaxError {_nativeError: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'
    at SyntaxError.BaseError …}

This is my app.module.ts

```
import 'hammerjs';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './modules/login/login.component';
import { Angular2RoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { WorkflowComponent } from './modules/workflow/workflow.component';
import { WorkflowHomeComponent } from './modules/workflow/workflow-home/workflow-home.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './modules/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminHomeComponent } from './modules/admin/admin-home/admin-home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './modules/profile/profile.component';

import { FlexLayoutModule, ObservableMedia } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    WorkflowComponent,
    WorkflowHomeComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AdminHomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Angular2RoutingModule,
    JsonpModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

This is my profile.component.html:

<md-card class="demo-card demo-basic">
      <md-card-content class="flex-container" style="width: 100%" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutAlign.xs="start">
      <form>
        <div class="flex-container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
          <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="30%" fxFlex.xs="40%">
            <md-input class="user-name" placeholder="User Name (disabled)" disabled value="Google">
            </md-input>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="30%" fxFlex.xs="40%">
            <md-input class="e-mail" placeholder="E-mail (disabled)" disabled value="Google">
            </md-input>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="30%" fxFlex.xs="40%">
            <md-input class="company" placeholder="Company (disabled)" disabled value="Google">
            </md-input>
          </div>
        </div>

  </form>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: You are importing `ObservableMedia` from the `@angular/flex-layout`, and then you'r not using it. Are you sure that's a valid import?

Comment: yes.I used it for hide side navigation using angular2 material. You sent me an answer.It is correct.But i want to hide the side navigation using angular2 material.I didn't put whole code of profile.component.html file here. For that purpose also need importing flex-layout.But when importing flex-layout it gives syntaxError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. When import the flex-layout in the beta.5 version it should be like this.

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout/flexbox';
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is stop using intelliej or webstorm and cd into your app root directory and do ng serve
it will solve the problem

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work. It still gives previous syntaxError.